# Who was invited to use the Comment Evaluator 5000?

Tags: discussion, comment-evaluator-5000

I learned about the [Comment Evaluator 5000](https://false-mammal.glitch.me/) through its [tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comment-evaluator-5000), and I gather from other questions that many users received an email inviting them to use it, but I did not. (Yes, I've checked my spam folder.) How were users selected to participate?

Comment: You had to respond to one of the blogs.

Comment: Think there was a link to a google docs form in one of the blogs where you could sign up. They then divided the people that signed up there into waves and invited them week by week.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the [survey](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdCQNtu4KHesQz-2AzRSl8z6d4_cLgPj4B7cjNpPePc-04seA/formResponse) (which has been closed) from [the "Welcoming" blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) included a checkbox asking whether you're available to be contacted for research/survey for the inclusive project.

Comment: To those saying it was the google docs survey... Dunno if that was _all_ that did it, because I got the invite and I don't recall doing that survey... Not to mention I can't do google docs surveys from my work machine, the only one I access SO on.